# Confusion about Nvidia driver

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

Newbie to linux, using ubuntu 14.04 LTS, my question is that I'm confused about the nvidia driver settings, with `nvidia-smi`, it gives

```
| NVIDIA-SMI 367.57                 Driver Version: 367.57                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 960M    Off  | 0000:01:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   41C    P8    N/A /  N/A |   1318MiB /  4043MiB |     13%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1103    G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                             238MiB |
|    0      1984    G   compiz                                         143MiB |
|    0      2499    G   ...el-token=97D71C8F7958A5CC7D7CFCDDCA9ED82B    96MiB |
|    0      6010    C   ...cc/Downloads/software/envs/py2/bin/python   789MiB |
|    0      7096    G   ...rWithCastExtension/Enabled/EnableSessionC    48MiB |
|    0      8760    G   /usr/bin/nvidia-settings                         0MiB |
```

and in Nvidia X server settings, in PRIME Profiles, it says I'm using NVIDIA card, not the Intel card, but in software and updates, with additional drivers, it shows that I'm using the nouveau driver, but also a
Nvidia 375 version driver which is not selected.(sorry I don't have enough reputation to post image) But with `dpkg -l|grep nvidia`, I only got the 367 version installed:

```
cc@cc-Lenovo-Rescuer-14ISK:~/Downloads$ dpkg -l|grep nvidia
ii  nvidia-367                                            367.57-0ubuntu0.14.04.1                             amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 367.57
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-367                                 367.57-0ubuntu0.14.04.1                             amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-prime                                          0.6.2.1                                             amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                                       367.48-0ubuntu1                                     amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

so my confusion is that: what I'm truly using? is this version 375 already installed in my system and I can switch to it? what the additional drivers option really do? Thanks in advance!

*EDIT*: `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D'` gives:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 191b (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 0001
    Kernel driver in use: i915_bpo
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Gaussian Mixture Model
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 0006
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

Comment: No, 375 is available, 367 is installed and running. 367 is also no longer distributed, hence its absence in the list. Yes, you can install and use 375 just by selecting and applying in Additional drivers. 375 is the current long support driver.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: The Nvidia driver is installed, I see no problems. You probably installed a driver not from the Ubuntu repos.

Comment: @Pilot6 They *could* have installed it before, from the repos, and later, probably since 14.04.5, the 367 version was removed and replaced by the new LTS version (375).

Comment: That's unlikely еру nvidia-367 package points to the 375 driver.

Comment: I have once tried to switch to nvidia-375, then reboot, but got black screen problem

Comment: What I'm mainly confused is in additional driver, it says that I'm using `nouveau`, but nvidia-smi says I'm using `nvidia-367`, so what's I'm truely using, why they are inconsistent?